# Restoring sudo.config file to default

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, authentication

I had my laptop running pretty well, slowly going about the process of finding apps that would match what I'd been using on Windows. I  cut and paste what I thought was installation for a Terminal with Root Privileges (Sudo 1.9 page); but, I didn't read the page carefully and downloaded python and altered the sudo.config file.

Now, I can no longer use sudo commands and can't run software installer and other applications. I tried making a second account with administrator privileges but it is exactly the same, and authentication is greyed out or access denied.

When I try to execute `sudo su` in terminal, I get the following:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 16 while loading plugin "python_policy"
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/python_plugin.so: No such file or directory
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I can't get in to edit the config file and can't find a default script for Ubuntu 20.04 even if I could. Any suggestions that might avoid a total reinstall would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to "get in" is sudo if not working:

1. Use `pkexec` instead of `sudo`.
2. Login using `grub` recovery console.
3. Boot with Ubuntu LiveUSB and fix your files.

Comment: With pkexec I still have authentication problem. I have tried grub recovery console; but, I am not sure what I am doing. Using visudo seems to open a temporary sudo.conf file that is blank.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for suggestions. I was able to fix the issue using recovery console. I was a total idiot Windows user and input file as /etc/sudo.config instead of sudo.conf, which is why I was getting a blank tmp file. Deleted the two lines referring to python plugins and everything works again!

Comment: Okay, I am still having authentication problems and cannot install or remove flatpak apps and snap store link is also broken. A shaky message with 'authentication unsuccessful' pops up very briefly on the screen. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both flatpak and snap-store but it has made no difference. When I run software updater I get message 'You stopped the Check for Updates' and when I click on settings it tells me the software is up-to-date. Already installed apps seem to work fine. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Essentially any app that requires administrator level password authorisation is not working properly, e.g. gparted.

Comment: Operator of unix-session:2 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.gnome.gparted for unix-process:14464:330530 [/bin/sh /usr/sbin/gparted] (owned by unix-user:raoul)